# How to make particles flicker?

Tags: particles

this is the particle system that I made:
https://gyazo.com/c646168b33b1db50c477d150f6b29b8a

I wanted to add flicker, the effect in which each individual particle blinks off and on on random pace. I maybe even want some of them to just turn transparency on and off so they wouldn't disappear completely when they flicker.

I thought about animating the material but it just turns all particles on and off all at once.

Is there a way to do it?

thanks

Comment: looks great, no idea how to help yet 

Comment: You could create a collection of particles, each one having its own material and an action on its Emission strength

Comment: Are you using Eevee or Cycles?

Comment: I am using Cycles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do it. The solution may depend on the final effect you want.

But if you are using Cycles, you can use 'Particle info' node ([documentation here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/particle_info.html), this node is Cycles only) and for example a mix between particle age and random value.

It also uses a noise texture to pick random values as the age changes.

The other nodes are just an example of how to influence the flickering frequency: you can either change the scale value so that the texture node variation is slower, or change the texture scale, or change the threshold which is used to keep the particle lit or transparent.

This shader setting is associated to the particle object.

[image]

But again, this is just an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the best solution.
This is the final result: https://gyazo.com/ce7be857b6812bb1a444055989f30af2

Comment: great, cool result!

Comment: Brilliant. I have to bookmark this solution. Great work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a collection of several particles, each particle has its own material with an *Emission* node, keyframe the *Strength* value of the *Emission* node so that it flickers at a different time. Of course the particles with the same material will be synchronized, so you need enough particles so that the synch is not noticeable.

[image]

Result with only 3 particles:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much